# Flutter convert Color to hex string

Tags: dart, flutter

How can I convert a flutter `Color` class instance into a hex string?

For example, I would like to convert `Colors.blue` to what would be `'#4286f4'`.

Usecase is letting the user choose a color and save it in the database as a hex color.

I have checked related questions and they are for converting the other way around.

Comment: To get the "HTML" color code without opacity use `#${Colors.blue.value.toRadixString(16).substring(2)}`

Comment: @Yann39 comment is a short and useful answer. Thanks

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can convert the `value` property (includes alpha) or the individual `red`, `green`, and `blue` properties to Hex using `int.toRadixString(16)`:

```
 var myColor = Colors.blue;
 var hex = '#${myColor.value.toRadixString(16)}';
```

Comment: Thanks Gunter! Only missed the subtracting the first 2 characters to have proper CSS hex colour.

`String hexString = '#' + color.value.toRadixString(16).substring(2, hexString.length);`

Comment: Or alternatively combine `#` wirh the hex values of the color compnents red, green, and blue (but not alpha) instead of `value`.

Comment: The code above fails to produce correct format when red is 0. For example `0x00ACC1` will convert to `#acc1`. You should use `'#${intColor.toRadixString(16).padLeft(6, '0')}'`

Comment: Also, if you want to always omit alpha then do `intColor = 0xFFFFFF & intColor` first.

Comment: This fails for `Colors.transparent`. You need to convert each component separately and concatenate, see answers below.

Answer (score 14):

You can add an extension to **`Color`** class to get **HexString** from the Color object itself directly.

```
extension HexColor on Color {
  /// Prefixes a hash sign if [leadingHashSign] is set to `true` (default is `true`).
  String toHex({bool leadingHashSign = true}) => '${leadingHashSign ? '#' : ''}'
      '${alpha.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}'
      '${red.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}'
      '${green.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}'
      '${blue.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}';
}
```

```dart
Color color = Colors.blue ; 
print(color.toHex());
```

Answer (score 12):

This is what I'm using:

```
extension ColorX on Color {
  String toHexTriplet() => '#${(value & 0xFFFFFF).toRadixString(16).padLeft(6, '0').toUpperCase()}';
}
```

Sample outputs: `#00FFFF` or `#FF69B4`

This code also makes sure that alpha is omitted ([@bakua's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55147586/flutter-convert-color-to-hex-string#comment108470210_55147696))

Some Flutter source code inspiration: [util.dart](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/master/lib/web_ui/lib/src/engine/util.dart#L359), [painting.dart](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/master/lib/ui/painting.dart#L352)

Comment: value & 0xFFFFFF do not work. any updates?

Answer (score 4):

This is my favorite way of handling color to string conversions. I use this really simple extension class.

```
extension HexColor on Color {
  /// String is in the format "aabbcc" or "ffaabbcc" with an optional leading "#".
  static Color fromHex(String hexString) {
    final buffer = StringBuffer();
    if (hexString.length == 6 || hexString.length == 7) buffer.write('ff');
    buffer.write(hexString.replaceFirst('#', ''));
    return Color(int.parse(buffer.toString(), radix: 16));
  }

  /// Prefixes a hash sign if [leadingHashSign] is set to `true` (default is `true`).
  String toHex({bool leadingHashSign = true}) => '${leadingHashSign ? '#' : ''}'
      '${red.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}'
      '${green.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}'
      '${blue.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}'
      '${alpha.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}';
}
```

Comment: I think you have the wrong order of components in `toHex`. Alpha should be first.

Answer (score 3):

Improved Code:

```
extension HexColor on Color {
  String _generateAlpha({required int alpha, required bool withAlpha}) {
    if (withAlpha) {
      return alpha.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0');
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }

  String toHex({bool leadingHashSign = false, bool withAlpha = false}) =>
      '${leadingHashSign ? '#' : ''}'
              '${_generateAlpha(alpha: alpha, withAlpha: withAlpha)}'                  
              '${red.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}'              
              '${green.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}'              
           '${blue.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}'
          .toUpperCase();
}
```

Usage:

```
pickerColor.toHex(withAlpha: true);
```

Comment: Best solution, cleanest + working.

Answer (score 0):

In flutter if `AA` is the alpha value in hex, `RR` the red value in hex, `GG` the green value in hex, and `BB` the blue value in hex, a color can be expressed as `const Color(0xAARRGGBB)` just remove the leading two symbols to get HEX value. `RRGGBB`

Answer (score -1):

Though the question is converting Color to Hex, if you want to store and retrieve Color information, I've used like this.

Save color data as int. `Colors.blue.value`

Retrieve data as int and pass it to Color class `Color(savedInt)`